# How to get User's bookmarked Posts in Laravel Blog App?

Tags: php, laravel, blogs

I'm currently working on BlogApp using laravel. My Question is how to get users bookmarked posts ? Im confused about Eloquent Model Relationship.Please Guide Me. Thank You.

Here is `UsersTable` Migration Schema :

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique()->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('image')->nullable()->default(null);
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}


public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('users');
}
}
```

Here is `PostsTable` Migration Schema :

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreatePostsTable extends Migration
{

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->text('title');
        $table->text('slug');
        $table->text('coverimage')->nullable()->default(null); 
        $table->text('body');
        $table->integer('user_id')->nullable();
        $table->integer('category_id')->nullable();
        $table->boolean('is_active')->default(true);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}


public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('posts');
}
}
```

Here is `BookmarksTable` Migration Schema :

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUserPostsBookmarks extends Migration
{

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('bookmarks', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->integer('post_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->timestamps();
    });   
}


public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('bookmarks');
}
}
```

Here is `UserModel`

```
<?php

namespace App\Model;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class User extends Authenticatable
{
use Notifiable;

protected $table='users';
public $primaryKey='id';

protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password','provider', 'provider_id'
];


protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];


  public function bookmarks(){
      return $this->hasMany('App\Model\Post','bookmarks','user_id','post_id')->where('is_active', 1)->with('user','category')->get();
  }

}
```

Here is `PostModel` :

```
<?php

namespace App\Model;

  use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
  use App\Model\Bookmark;
  use App\Model\User;

class Post extends Model
{

protected $table='posts';
public $primaryKey='id';

public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\User','user_id');
}

public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\Category','category_id');
}

 public function bookmarks()
 {
 return $this->belongsToMany('App\Model\User', 'bookmarks','post_id','user_id');
 }

public function is_bookmarked(User $user){
    return $this->bookmarks->contains($user);
}

}
```

Here is `Bookmark` Model :

```
<?php

namespace App\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Bookmark extends Model
{
protected $table='bookmarks';   
}
```

I have also created 2 functions for adding and removing bookmarks in `PostsController`

```
    public function add_bookmark(Post $post)
    {
      Auth::user()->bookmarks()->attach($post->id);
      return back();
    }

   public function remove_bookmark(Post $post)
   {
    Auth::user()->bookmarks()->detach($post->id);
    return back();
   }
```

and also created method for get users bookmarked posts in `UserController`

```
    public function get_bookmarks(){
    $bookmarks=auth()->user()->bookmarks();
    return response()->json($bookmarks);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the relationship to `belongsToMany()`:

```
public function bookmarks()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Model\Post', 'bookmarks', 'user_id', 'post_id')->where('is_active', 1);
}
```

Then use it:

```
$user->bookmarks
```

Comment: Got this error : LogicException
Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation

Comment: @SaurabhMistry you're getting this error because you haven't changed the `bookmarks` relationship in `User` model as I've shown. You're using `get()` which returns Eloquent collection and not Relation object.

Comment: Thankyou It Works , can u explain me in detail why it is not working before

Comment: Your bookmarks table hasn't increment id column

You must add to $table->increments('id'); to your bookmarks migration.

Comment: @FGDeveloper `bookmarks` table doesn't need primary key, because it's a pivot table.

Comment: @Alexey Mezenin , How can i show bookmarked posts with pagination ,when i do this in UserModel return $this->belongsToMany('App\Model\Post','bookmarks','user_id','post_id')->where('is_active', 1)->with('user','category')->paginate(10);   ...it will give me same error

Comment: @SaurabhMistry do not use the relation method for that, just create a query in a model or in a controller. Also, if you want to build pagination for posts, use `Post` model, not `User`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you use a table between the actual data you need as link then this would be a excellent choice for Pivot table relation https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017/episodes/30

It knows bookmarks only hold the links between the User and the Posts

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Model\Post', 'bookmarks', 'user_id', 'post_id');
```

The second argument "bookmarks" is the table to use as pivot table.

> In addition to customizing the name of the joining table, you may also customize the column names of the keys on the table by passing additional arguments to the belongsToMany method. The third argument is the foreign key name of the model on which you are defining the relationship, while the fourth argument is the foreign key name of the model that you are joining to: